# Control network image quality in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, resolution, networkimageview

I am building a flutter ebook app. When the user is reading, the images take quite a while to load since they are over 1 mb in size. This is not a problem for most users with a decent internet connection, but for many others it is. Is it possible to control the quality of the image when being loaded from the internet by controlling how much to download, similar to when you search google images and the images progressively become more vibrant and their resolution increases,but in my case I stop it at a certain quality decided by the user. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to solve this on the server side and have an option in the Flutter app to choose the quality. An example would be to have 5 versions of each image at 5 quality levels and let the user choose the quality level. You can then have a quality parameter in the url you fetch images from. Let's say that the user wants page 12 of a book with a quality level of 2, the url can be something like
"https://mybackend.com/book-title/12/2".

Implementing this solely in Flutter won't solve the internet issue. The app will still download a 1MB image and then you could compress it before showing it but that won't matter.